# what is the correct way to programmatically set checkboxes (MultiOptionsFieldData) in a migration? (solved)

Tags: craft3, migration, entries-field, checkboxes

I need to update existing entries after the creation of a checkbox fields, to apply the default value to everything that was created before the availability of the new field.
The code should run in a migration to be deployed along the changes in the project config.

What is the correct way to programmatically set checkboxes (`craft\fields\data\MultiOptionsFieldData`)?

I verified the migration updates the entry (the title for instance), but not the custom field:

```php
$entries = \craft\elements\Entry::find()
  ->section('sectionProduct')
  ->all();

foreach($entries as $entry) {
  $options = $entry->distribution->getOptions();
  foreach($options as $opt) {
    $opt->selected = true;
  }
  $entry->distribution->setOptions($options);
  Craft::$app->getElements()->saveElement($entry);
}
```

After running the migration, the control panel never shows the checkboxes flagged (the checkbox field has two possible values).

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sleeping on it (and peeking at the db) provided a solution, with even simpler code:

```php
$entries = \craft\elements\Entry::find()
  ->section('sectionProduct')
  ->all();

foreach($entries as $entry) {
  $entry->setFieldValue('distribution', ["1", "2"]);
  Craft::$app->getElements()->saveElement($entry);
}
```

where `"1"` and `"2"` are the values associated to the checkboxes.

If you know the checkbox values, use `setFieldValue` and pass them as an array:

- `[]` (empty) no checkboxes selected
- `["single value"]`
- `["multi", "values"]`